# Печатать каждое число и затем считать двойками в обратном направлении

Tags: java

Напишите программу, которая считает от 1 до 15, печатает каждое число и затем считает двойками в обратном направлении до 1, снова печатая каждое число.

Что значить "считает двойками"? Что-то правда не понял, люди добрые объясните!

Comment: Может, имеет смысл задать этот вопрос тому, кто поставил перед вами эту задачу?

Comment: Это упражнение в книге по java."Java в примерах"

Comment: ну значит, либо книгу переводил какой-то надмозг, либо ее редактор был нетрезв

Answer (score 3):

Типа так?

```
for(int i=1; i <= 15; i++)
   System.out.println(i);
for(int i=15; i>0; i-=2) {
   System.out.println(i);
   if(i > 1)
      System.out.println(i-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Скорей всего вот так:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
for (int i = 15; i >= 1; i-=2){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: На обратном проходе надо печатать каждое число...

Answer (score -1):

Или так:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
for (int i = 15; i >= 1; i-=2){
    System.out.println(i + " " + (i - 1) + " ");
}
```